# Why is MATLAB's string sorting algorithm different than Windows'?

Tags: string, matlab, sorting

I have many wav files that each one of them is mapped by name and other
information with an excel file.

I sorted the excel file by name and also the folder that contains all the wav
files - both sorting turned out the same.

When I tried to iterate all these files via MATLAB, the order was not sorted as mentioned above. so I 'manually' sorted all of the files (using `sortrows`)  but still the sorting stayed the same.

So the question is why? and how do I match the 2 different sortings?

1st is MATLAB's sorting, second is Windows explorer's.

[image: MATLAB's] [image: Windows']

Comment: For why it is happening and how to fix this: you have a dupe from  [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-do-some-sorting-methods-sort-by-1-10-2-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Windows is sorted by name (or whatever you choose), but Matlab for sure it's using inode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode to make order on dir command.